# Abstract types in pointcuts

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, aop, pointcut

I'd like to intercept method calls with a certain signature with an [Aspect](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html).

My pointcut should look something like this:

`execution(public Result * (Input))"`

But `Result` and `Input` are `abstract`.

Would this pointcut also match all Methods, that return a subtype of `Result` and work with a subtype of `Input`? Because that's my intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very nearly. You need to add a plus sign immediately after the type name.

```
execution(public Result+ * (Input+))
```

Here is an example from [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/idioms.html) doc. Spring uses a restricted version of the AspectJ syntax.

```
pointcut callToUndefinedMethod():
    call(* AbstractFacade+.*(..))
    && !call(* AbstractFacade.*(..));
```

And here is the (terse) [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/quick-typePatterns.html)

> SubtypePattern - all types in SubtypePattern, a pattern with a +.